# Fire a query that minimum connection with server database and minimum use memory of server database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I have a two tables category and subcategory..

Details of tables

tbl_category : cat_id,cat_name 
tbl_subcategory : subcat_id, cat_id, subcat_name

In this tbl_category i have 10 category data, 
and in tbl_subcategory i have 50 subcategory data means each category has 5 sub category.

Now, i have to fire a query that minimum connection with server database and minimum use memory of server database..

How can i do this.??

Thanks in advance
JIGAR

Comment: What is your query supposed to return? What do you have so far? Why is what you have so far not sufficient for your purpose?

Comment: i have listing a category record and when i click each category i have popup via javascript ya ajax to listing there subcategory for particular cat_id.... will try to minimum load on server bcz i have lots of data for this but for  this example i used 10 category and 5 subcategory for each category. i will finding mysql query for this..

Comment: Again, what have you tried? Why doesn't it work?